# Common Markdown Code Syntax for Kramdown

Tags: markdown, jekyll, kramdown

Is there any way to modify Kramdown through configuration options which will allow me to use Common Markdown/GFM fenced code block syntax, i.e.

````
```
here's the code!
```
````

I'm switching to Kramdown for my blog so I can have Markdown inside other elements, but most of my blog uses GFM for this, and it's how I normally write code in Markdown so it'd be cool if there was some way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your **_config.yml** add

```
kramdown:
  input: GFM
```

See [documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#kramdown)

Comment: Aha! Thanks David. I'll give this a go later.